# how can emacs set color for specific symbols

Tags: ruby, emacs, clojure, elisp

i use osx 10.9.4 and emacs 24.3.1
now my emacs works fine

but i want to change the highlight color of equal sign and the numbers in the code instead of white color

and i tried to write down a elisp script in the dot file

```
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook
  (lambda () (font-lock-add-keywords 
               nil 
               '(("[^a-zA-Z]\\([0-9]+\\)[^a-zA-Z]" 
                  1 font-lock-warning-face prepend)))))
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook
  (lambda () (font-lock-add-keywords 
               nil 
               '(("\\(=\\)" 
                  1 font-lock-warning-face prepend)))))
```

i can change color of equal sign and numbers in the code now with the elisp script but it also change the color of equal sign and numbers in string and comment, so how can i make it right?

Comment: Better not quote your lambdas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the prepend flag. This tells font-lock that it should color every instance of the match even if it was already colored.

Also after-change-major-mode-hooks are a poor choice for this you should add the keywords directly to ruby mode keywords in your config.

```lisp
(eval-after-load "ruby-mode"
    '(font-lock-add-keywords 'ruby-mode
       ...
     ))
```